# Hierarchical scoring Lucene, OR term treatment

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval, scoring, booleanquery

I was trying to translate an interest profile into some Lucene query.

Given a title term and some expansion term, in JSON format, such as

`{"title":"Donald Trump", "Expansion":[["republic","republican"],["democratic","democrat"],["campaign"]]}`

The corresponding Lucene query can be a BooleanQuery like following (Set title term boost factor as 3.0 while expansion term boost factor as 1.0).

`+(text:donald^3.0 text:trump^3.0 (text:democrat text:democratic) (text:republic text:republican) text:campaign)`

Using `IndexSearcher's explain()` method,

A matching document like,

`I know people just want to find a way to be famous without taking any risks, republic republican Donald Trump Campaign.`

has a scoring of 9.0

```
3.0 = weight(text:donald^3.0 in 0) [TitleExpansionSimilarity], result of:
    3.0 = score(doc=0,freq=1.0), product of:
      3.0 = queryWeight, product of:
        3.0 = boost
        1.0 = idf(docFreq=201, maxDocs=201)
        1.0 = queryNorm
      1.0 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.0 = idf(docFreq=201, maxDocs=201)
        1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=0)
  3.0 = weight(text:trump^3.0 in 0) [TitleExpansionSimilarity], result of:
    3.0 = score(doc=0,freq=1.0), product of:
      3.0 = queryWeight, product of:
        3.0 = boost
        1.0 = idf(docFreq=201, maxDocs=201)
        1.0 = queryNorm
      1.0 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.0 = idf(docFreq=201, maxDocs=201)
        1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=0)
  2.0 = sum of:
    1.0 = weight(text:republic in 0) [TitleExpansionSimilarity], result of:
      1.0 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.0 = idf(docFreq=201, maxDocs=201)
        1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=0)
    1.0 = weight(text:republican in 0) [TitleExpansionSimilarity], result of:
      1.0 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.0 = idf(docFreq=201, maxDocs=201)
        1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=0)
  1.0 = weight(text:campaign in 0) [TitleExpansionSimilarity], result of:
    1.0 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:
      1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
      1.0 = idf(docFreq=201, maxDocs=201)
      1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=0)
```

Is there any way to rewrite Lucene scoring function, to score the BooleanQuery (text:republic text:republican) aka. cluster `["republic","republican"]` as a maximum of either the matching weight of "republic" or the matching weight of "republican"?

```
1.0 = MAX(instead of sum) of:
    1.0 = weight(text:republic in 0) [TitleExpansionSimilarity], result of:
      1.0 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.0 = idf(docFreq=201, maxDocs=201)
        1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=0)
    1.0 = weight(text:republican in 0) [TitleExpansionSimilarity], result of:
      1.0 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.0 = idf(docFreq=201, maxDocs=201)
        1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not via Lucene's QueryParser syntax, but you can use a [`DisjunctionMaxQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DisjunctionMaxQuery.html), instead of a `BooleanQuery` to combine queries and score with the maximum score of it's subqueries, instead of the sum of the subqueries' scores.